# Best way to use multiple URL paramemetrs for advacned filtering with PHP?

Tags: php

I wonder if there is a "simple" PHP solution to create multiple URL parameters. Until now I am able to create a "one click" filter like this:

```
$url_param = ($_GET["sort"]);
<a href="?sort=rank-chipset">Sort by this</a>
```

and then:

```
if($url_param == 'rank-chipset') {do this}
```

This works great as a "one click" URL parameter for filtering! I like this simple solution to do things with URL parameters, but can't figure out how to do something similar so i can give the option to users to select multiple parameters, like brand1, brand2, year 2021 and more.

I would prefer this to work like this: If users clicks brand1 filter then instantly reload page and show brand1 products, after if also clicks brand2 then show also brand1 and brand2 products. If users clicks again brand1 remove brand1 from filtering.

Comment: You as the developer need to keep track of this. When they click brand1, you can programmatically include that in the brand2 links, or you could stash that to a cookie or session.

Comment: Holding the past selections in the session array will be much cleaner than bloating the url's query string.  Shopping carts don't bloat their urls with this kind of stuff.

Comment: @mickmackusa I disagree - having search parameters in the URL means you can bookmark or share that URL, use the browser's built-in history functionality, open multiple searches in different tabs, etc; that's far more important to me than whether the address bar looks pretty. Sessions should be reserved for tracking *state*, like a shopping basket, which you want to be independent of the user's navigation around the site.

Comment: Fine points.  I prefer my advice.  You may prefer yours.  If a permalink is desirable, offer a button to spit out a built url.

Comment: @mickmackusa Certainly, you can spend a bunch of effort recreating some of the things that web browsers have had built in for decades; but why bother, for something that's this simple to do with a good old-fashioned query string?

Comment: @Man Depending on context, some might advise that using javascript might be appropriate instead of forcing a whole page reload on every selection.  We probably don't have enough knowledge of your actual business logic.  We don't know if you only have a handful of options or hundreds of options.  We don't know what you are going to display based on the values in the cache.  There is a real probability that refreshing a whole page simply because a user makes a single action is an inefficient use of resources. Might the UX be improved by using a multi-select field? Is this merely a sorting task?

Comment: @mickmackusa You are right about resources, but with good caching is not an issue. I will make about 20 different filters. My WordPress theme is totally custom and it's really fast and well optimized so it want be an issue for users experience. Also it might be better for SEO when users redirect to many page while selecting filters. I also love clean PHP solutions instead of js :P

Also i did research TOP sites that are using filters and they work the same way, but with js. I also believe adding a button to load all selected filters it might be not so good for user experience at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `filter` parameter a comma-delimited list of filters. Then combine the existing value of `$_GET['filter']` with the filter for that link.

```
function add_or_remove_filter($new, $filters) {
    $pos = array_search($new, $filters);
    if ($pos === false) {
        // add if not found
        $filters[] = $new;
    } else {
        /remove if found
        unset($filters[$pos]);
    }
    return implode(',', $filters);
}
$filters = explode(',', $_GET['filter'] ?? '');
?>
<a href="?filter=<?php echo add_or_remove_filter("brand1", $filters); ?>">Brand 1</a>
<a href="?filter=<?php echo add_or_remove_filter("brand2", $filters); ?>">Brand 2</a>
<a href="?filter=<?php echo add_or_remove_filter("2021", $filters); ?>">Year 2021</a>
```

Comment: I wonder if any of the values will have commas in them (now or int the future).  This is more or less a warning to the asker and researchers to develop with care.

Comment: @mickmackusa Since he's designing the filtering system, he can ensure that they don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to design a solution that writes the navigation history directly in the url, then set up the storage with the goal of easy/swift data mutation.

Code: (untested)

```
function toggleItem($item, $cache) {
    $cache[$item] = isset($cache[$item]) ? null : 1;
    return $cache;
}

// show array_keys($_GET) as you wish

$allItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    printf(
        '<a href="?%s">%s</a>',
        http_build_query(toggleItem($item, $_GET)),
        $item
    );
}
```

The advantage in this is that the values are always stored as array keys.  This means checking for their existence is optimized for speed and `http_build_query()` will ensure that a valid querystring is generated.

A special (perhaps unexpected for the unknowing developer) behavior of `http_build_query()` ensures that an element with a `null` value will be stripped from its output (the key will not be represented at all). This acts as if `unset()` was used on the array.

If you want keep these item values in a specific subarray of `$_GET`, you can adjust the snippet for that too.  You would set this up with `$_GET['nav'] ?? []` and access `array_keys($_GET['nav'] ?? [])`. One caveat to this performance boost is that PHP's array keys may not be floats -- they get automatically converted to integers.  (I don't know the variability of your items.)

Comment: @Manos I am curious why you have commented that the other answer was "perfect" but mentioned nothing about my similar solution.  Did you understand my solution?  Is there an aspect of my solution that is not suitable for your project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try your solution but it replaces the URL and i don't know how exactly http_build_query works and code seems that needs some editing. It might be a better solution for more experienced devs.

Comment: Right you are Manos, I failed to prepend a `?` to the generated querystring when building the href value.  Fixed now.  `http_build_query()` is important because it will deliver a valid querystring from the supplied array.